# Passing a ptr to a ptr to A as parameter to a function of A is bad practice?

Tags: c++

Is passing a pointer to a pointer to object A as a parameter of a function in A bad practice?

Here's an example:

```
class A
{
    A** ptrToMyself;

    void Foo(A*& refToPtrToMyself)
    {
        ptrToMyself = &refToPtrToMyself;
    }
}
class B
{
    A* ptrToA;
    void Bar()
    {
        ptrToA = new A();
        ptrToA->Foo(ptrToA);
    }
}
```

The reason I need this is that B will create an instance of A, then A will run and will destroy itself later. Since I don't want to have an invalid pointer in B I set that pointer to nullptr.

**EDIT:**

So, as some have asked I'm going to clarify what I'm going to be using this for. I'm making a game in UE4 and, basically, class A represents the Attack class I have (I inherit it and override some virtual functions to add functionality) and B represents my character class. When the player presses the attack button I instantiate the class of the attack the player has selected. Then the attack executes, plays animations and does all it has to do. When it finishes it just destroys itself (and clears the reference the character had to it).

Comment: `ptrToMyself` should be `A*` not `A**`. How is `ptrToMyself` different than using `this`? Im a bit worried about your use case. Sounds like u need to use reference counting smart pointers.

Comment: Just to clear this up, this is so you can `void commitsuicide() { *ptrToMyself = nullptr; delete this;}`, yes? I don't like this. If you expand on the usage of `A` and its relationship to `B` someone may suggest a better design.

Comment: I think this is bad design. Impossible to tell what you're trying to use it for, but I can almost guarantee there's a better solution that involves `A` not committing suicide.

Comment: There's probably a much better/cleaner/safer way of doing whatever it is you are trying to do with `std::shared_ptr` and possibly `std::weak_ptr` and/or `std::shared_from_this`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Unreal Engine has its own smart pointer classes (like weak ptr and shared ptr) but as far as I understand the weak pointer, it will only be set to nullptr after GC happens. So if A destroyed itself I will have an invalid pointer in B until GC happens. I can force GC to happen, but I don't like that idea.

Comment: In my experience things will go a lot better for you if you just don't use raw pointers at all.  (But maybe this engine requires it, IDK)

Comment: @M.M UE4 has a base class called UObject and basically, any raw pointer to a UObject gets transformed into a smart pointer under the hood. UE4's smart pointers are meant to be used for everything that is not a UObject.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a pointer to the instance doesn't make sense at all—that's already what the `this` pointer is.

The bigger problem here is that you haven't thought enough about the determinants of the lifetime of your objects and more generally about the underlying asynchronicity and the conflicts it might raise etc.

Asynchronous animations basically mean that your animation classes need to hold shared pointers to all objects they will need (attacks etc.). That's precisely why shared pointers exist; you can initialize a shared pointer in some member function of B, make a copy of it in some non-blocking animation function, then it doesn't matter if you get rid of the shared pointer that B holds, the object will exist as long as some animation object holds on a pointer to it. And if your `b` keeps a `weak_ptr` to the `shared_ptr` of `a` that exist elsewhere, the `b` can keep track of whether `a` has been destroyed.

Anyway, the main question is where do you keep track of ongoing animations?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the attack to delete itself. Just use a smart pointer (std or UE4) and let it delete itself:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class AttackInterface
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Attack: public AttackInterface
{
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "deal damage" << std::endl;}
};

class Character
{
public:
    void behave()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Attack> attack = std::make_shared<Attack>();
        attack->foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Character c;
    c.behave();
}
```

Comment: Idk if you saw my comment there, but since GC happens in an interval (not on every frame) I don't want to use smart pointers because I might have an invalid reference after I destroyed the object and GC hasn't happened.

Comment: That is not how GC works in C++. You don't delete the object (so: you can't have an invalid reference after you destroy it). You create a smart pointer. As long as anyone has it, the object exists. Once everybody discard the pointer, the object is deleted.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the Character to control the lifespan of the Attack, I only want a reference to it to check if it is still happening (pointer should be null if it's not) and for UI and other systems to get info about the attack. The character shouldn't control when the attack is destroyed. The attack itself should determine when it has finished all work it had to do, and when it gets destroyed the pointer to the attack in Character should become null.

Comment: The thing is. If the attack controls when it gets destroyed, it means that while it does performs that control, there exists a pointer to it, somewhere (within UE4 animation engine, most likely). This should prevent the attack from getting deleted, until the animation is over.

Comment: Well, no. The animation system doesn't care about the attack. The attack just calls a function to my animation class. The only things that reference the attack are the player and what calls the Tick function every frame on the attack. It can be safely destroyed using a UE4 function.